# Why display inline-block breaks overflow-wrap: break-word

Tags: html, css

I have a container that has `overflow-wrap: break-word;` every child element breaks the word nicely except one anchor tag that has `display: inline-block;`. Why does that happen?

```css
a {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #006fdd;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
   max-width: 100px;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
   background-color: yellow;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="inline-block">display: inline-block longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongtext@something</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <a>display: inline longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongtext@something</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongtext@something</div>
</div>
```

Comment: display: inline-block allows to set a width and height on the element.

Also, with display: inline-block, the top and bottom margins/paddings are respected

Comment: max-width: 100%; to the inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inline-block, you should define `width` so CSS knows where to break the word.

```css
a {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #006fdd;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px; /* define width here */
}
.container {
   max-width: 100px;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
   background-color: yellow;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="inline-block">display: inline-block longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongtext@something</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <a>display: inline longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongtext@something</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongtext@something</div>
</div>
```